# Opinions on having (weekly) topic challenges?

Tags: discussion

What do I mean by topic challenges? Basically, this: [How do weekly topic challenges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work). Every week or so, someone (for example, me) makes a post here on meta about a topic to encourage people to ask questions on a particular topic.

Until now I’ve been running a similar thing over on [/r/conlangs](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/wiki/events/topic-discussions), but there it was more about open discussions, and kinda not very successful. However, I feel like doing so here could increase overall activity on the site. In addition, I would have an excuse to advertize the StackExchange on the subreddit once a week, telling people to come here if they have a question on a particular topic.

Some example topics might be:

- Various linguistics topics such as Morphosyntactic Alignment or Tense/Aspect/Moods/Evidentiality
- Connections between worldbuilding and conlangs (e.g. “How might languages in setting X be different”, “non-human languages”)
- “Everything about loglangs”
- Questions about a particular popular conlang
- “Developing writing systems”

If the idea is well-received, I shall assemble an actual list of topics and start next week. If not, back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the challenge is to write good questions on these topics, not to pose challenges to answerers, as [proposed here](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/136/113).

Comment: Ready to get started?

Comment: I guess I’ll start this Friday, that fine with everyone?

Answer (score 2):

I believe these topic challenges would be both a good opportunity to encourage existing members to post more often and to bring new members to the site. That said, a week seems a bit short to me given our site's slow activity at the moment -- so I suggest challenges **every two weeks** instead.

Comment: This could be interesting; as far as the interval, why not do it weekly as proposed, but allow two or three challenges to be running in parallel (that is, on any given week, there would be three topics "open", and one of those topics "ages out" each week, with a new one coming in).

Comment: I think two weeks would be better, we don't want to run out of challenge categories too quickly.