# Topics for Topic Challenges

Tags: discussion, challenge

In [Opinions on having (weekly) topic challenges?](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/opinions-on-having-weekly-topic-challenges?cb=1) I asked whether we wanted to have topic challenges, that is essentially meta threads encouraging users to ask topics on a specific topics. I would like to start these on Friday (in two days), and we need to collect some interesting topics. Topics can, but don’t have to, be associated with a tag, e.g. [phonology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology). The challenges will remain up for two weeks, so they should be somewhat broad to allow for many kinds of questions.

For convenience’s sake, simply make an answer for each topic, perhaps with some example questions or an explanation for the scope of the topic.

Comment: Will there be another featured post announcing each topic challenge, or will that be incorporated into this post, in which case how do we easily see which one is current?

Comment: There will be a new post so we can easily promote it. The main question is how do we keep this one here visible, cause keeping it featured isn't really an option. I guess I'll just link back to it every time.

Comment: Linking back to it seems easiest

Answer (score 4):

## Writing systems

Many conlangers like to develop new writing systems for their conlangs.

Associated tags: [writing-systems](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems)

Answer (score 3):

**Phonology**

Many conlangs start at the phonology, i.e. the sound system. As such I reckon many (particularly inexperienced) conlangers have unanswered questions about this topic, both specific their own conlangs (regarding naturalism and the likes) and as a general linguistic topic.

Associated tags: [phonology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology), [phonetics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics), [naturalism](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naturalism)

---

This challenge has been run:
[Topic Challenge: Phonology](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/146/113)

Answer (score 3):

## Conlang communities

Questions about real-life communities of conlangers. Questions could be about finding or starting clubs (though not specific recommendations), how to sustain a speech community, perhaps how to teach someone your conlang

Associated tags: [conlang-learning](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-learning), [speech-communities](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-communities)

---

Now running: [Topic Challenge: Conlanging Communities](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/topic-challenge-conlanging-communities)

Answer (score 3):

## Language contact

Questions about how to simulate language contact in a conlang, including borrowing, pidginisation and creolisation, code switching, sociolinguistics and prestige languages/dialects/registers...

Associated tags: [borrowings](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borrowings), [code-switching](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-switching), [creoles](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creoles), [diachronics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diachronics), [pidgin](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pidgin), [relexification](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relexification)

---

This challenge has been run: [Topic Challenge: Language Contact](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/topic-challenge-language-contact)

Answer (score 2):

## Modified Hangul

As a South Korean myself. Let me have a solemn introduction of this propose.

### Abstract

> 온누리의 말이 나라마다 달라 문자가 서로 통하지 아니하니, 이런 까닭으로 사람끼리 말하고자 하는 바가 있어도 결국 각자의 뜻을 능히 전달하지 못하는 경우가 많으니라. 내 이를 가엾게 여겨 기존 스물여덟 자에 <???> 자를 더하노니, 사람마다 하여금 쉽게 익혀 날로 씀에 편안케 하고자 할 따름이니라.
>
> Because languages of the world differ by nationalities and their scripts aren't compatible, people have difficulties when they're trying to communicate. I lamented on this, so here I add <???> characters to existing 28 characters, in hope that everyone will easily learn the resulting new script and use it conveniently.

### Objective

Though I don't intend to actually replace scripts of natlangs, I expect that a modified Hangul can be a more practical replacement of phonetic alphabets such as the IPA. Furthermore, conlangs would be able to freely adopt the modified Hangul as its script. Let's see how far we can go.

Answer (score 1):

## TAME

Tense-Aspect-Modality-Evidentiality are core parts of verbal morphology. Every(?) natlang will gramatically express at least one of these. Lots of scope for questions here.

Tags: [tense-aspect-mood](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tense-aspect-mood), [modals](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modals), [morphology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morphology)

---

This challenge has been run:
[Topic Challenge: Tense/Aspect/Mood/Evidentiality](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/topic-challenge-tense-aspect-mood-evidentiality?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

**Specific conlang: Klingon**

Questions about Klingon.

I choose this specific conlang because it attracts a lot of views, and there are people here to ask and answer questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Specific conlang: Toki Pona**

Questions about Toki Pona.

Answer (score 0):

## Tenses

Questions about expression of temporal actions (past, present, future) with the action of verbs (eat, ate, will eat) as it varies through conlangs, and building the changes necessary in a language to express different temporal tenses.

---

Comment: We did just run the TAM topic challenge which included this. No problem running another more specific challenge later, but I think we'd want to wait a while and cover other topics first.