# Topic Challenge: Tense/Aspect/Mood/Evidentiality

Tags: discussion, challenge

## This challenge has ended!

Good day everyone,

I’m happy to announce our first Topic Challenge. What is a topic challenge? Basically, it’s just a call for more questions. Every two weeks on friday I will announce the new topic and it’ll be featured for everyone on the SE to see. Your mission is to ask questions on that topic, direct people here who might have questions and so on.

As a first topic, we shall start with Tense/Aspect/Mood/Evidentiality (TAME for short). Are you working on a conlang and are unsure if the interplay of your modals with the aspect system makes sense? Do you want to understand how Ithkuil’s mood system differs from that of natlangs or whether Lojban has anything like evidentiality marking ([it does](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lojban/Attitudinals#Evidentials:))? Then now is the perfect time to ask these quesitons.

Additionally, if you have an idea for an interesting topic that you think might generate good questions, please reply in this thread: [Topics for Topic Challenges](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/topics-for-topic-challenges).

Ask ahead!

Comment: Can [my](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/674/is-there-any-importance-of-dots-while-constructing-alphabets-for-a-language) question consider part of it?

Comment: @Karan It doesn't really seem related to this topic to me.

Answer (score 1):

Questions:

- [Is there existing terminology for distinguishing multiple imperative moods?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/670/113)
- [What are the aspects of Esperanto?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/672/what-are-the-aspects-of-esperanto)
- [Are there constructed languages with a tense system inspired by Relativity Theory?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/827/113)