# Topic Challenge: Phonology

Tags: discussion, challenge

## Challenge ended

Two weeks have passed, and the first topic challenge has ended. Sadly, we didn’t see a large increase in questions, but let’s keep going anyway!

This time round, we shall go with the topic of **Phonology**. I expect and hope that there are many an open question for this topic. So, please go ahead and see if you can’t ask some!

Furthermore, we *really* need more topic suggestions or this series will find a quick end. Please submit them as answers on this thread: [Topics for Topic Challenges](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/topics-for-topic-challenges)

Answer (score 2):

Questions:

- [Which IPA phonemes can be made and understood underwater?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/685/113) (technically this was asked just before the challenge started, but give it some love too)
- [What are sounds that I have to include in my phonology for it to be naturalistic?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/690/113)
- [Designing a mildly weird phonology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/699/designing-a-mildly-weird-phonology)
- [What reasons would there be for not having a human conlang with only vowels?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/707/what-reasons-would-there-be-for-not-having-a-human-conlang-with-only-vowels)