# Topic Challenge: Language Contact

Tags: discussion, challenge

## Challenge Over

Another two weeks, and [this time](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/53) we’ve seen a bit more participation. Way to go! Plus, a bunch more topics have been suggested so we can keep going for a while. Woot!

This fortnight, the topic is **Language Contact**:

> Questions about how to simulate language contact in a conlang, including borrowing, pidginisation and creolisation, code switching, sociolinguistics and prestige languages/dialects/registers...

It’s a very interesting topic, maybe I can come up with a question or two too? If you have an interesting topic too, submit it here: [Topics for Topic Challenges](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/topics-for-topic-challenges)

Answer (score 1):

Question belonging to this topic challenge:

- [Slang in Esperanto](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/719/slang-in-esperanto) On the slang register in Esperanto