# Topic Challenge: Conlanging Communities

Tags: discussion, challenge

Last fortnights’s topic challenge wasn’t that much of a success, sadly; maybe this one will see some more activity!

**Conlanging Communities**

Questions about real-life communities of conlangers. Questions could be about finding or starting clubs (though not specific recommendations), how to sustain a speech community, perhaps how to teach someone your conlang.

---

As always, post recommendations for future topics here: [Topics for Topic Challenges](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/topics-for-topic-challenges)

Comment: It can be easier to think up topics than questions sadly.

Comment: Definitely true

Comment: Maybe don't post the next topic immediately, let this sit un-featured for two weeks, and then post it? I'm still trying to think of questions to ask :(

Comment: I can most certainly do that. (stupid minimum characters)

Answer (score 1):

Questions belonging to this topic

- [What are some real world data on the numbers of speakers of constructed languages?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/743/what-are-some-real-world-data-on-the-numbers-of-speakers-of-constructed-language) What data on conlang speakers are available?
- [How many active Klingon speakers are there?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/766/how-many-active-klingon-speakers-are-there) How many active Klingon speakers are there?